# Python : Flatten xml, extract only the direct child without nested child

Tags: python, xml

I am looking to flatten the xml to csv, and for each nested child entries, i want to replicate the value of direct child entry which both has same tag names. Here is the sample xml. For each value "entry" inside the "claim" tag, i want to print the values of all  for the direct child of "Insurer". I did try with findall but its retrieving the values of "entry" under "claim" as well.

Note: I'm Using ElementTree to parse

```
<Parent>
       <Branch>
             <Insurer>
                  <claim>                    
                     <entry>1</entry>
                     <entry>2</entry>
                  </claim>
                  <entry>outer</entry>
                  <entry>outer1</entry>
                  <entry>outer2</entry>
              </Insurer>
        </Branch>
</Parent>
```

```
Entry= child.findall('.//{http://trying.nz}entry')
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
entry_from_claim,entry_from_Insurer
1,outer
1,outer1
1,outer2
2,outer
2,outer1
2,outer2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to mention the xml parsing library you're using, but here's an example of working code based on ElementTree.

It does make assumptions about the structure of the XML data by using the `find` function that only goes one level deep.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                          

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET                                          

from csv import writer as csvwriter                                         
from itertools import product                                                  

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")                                                   

claims = [                                                                     
    entry.text                                                                 
    for entry in tree.find("Branch")                                           
    .find("Insurer")                                                           
    .find("claim")                                                             
    .findall("entry")                                                          
]                                                                              
insurers = [                                                                   
    entry.text                                                                 
    for entry in tree.find("Branch").find("Insurer").findall("entry")          
]                                                                              

with open("output.csv", "w") as csvfile:                                       
    outputwriter = csvwriter(csvfile)                                            
    outputwriter.writerow(("entry_from_claim", "entry_from_Insurer"))            
    outputwriter.writerows(product(claims, insurers))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I am using Element Tree, I will try your solution.